# ¿Cómo usar el script de python del API V3 de Google para actualizar videos de YouTube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, youtube

Estoy intendando usar el código de Python que Google ha publicado en esta página para actulizar videos de YouTube.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es-419

Ya he probado otros ejemplos como por ejemplo el de subir videos y me han funcioado bien, pero con este tengo problemas.

Bueno, antes que nada decir que si alguien lo quiere probar usando Python 3 va a tener que cambiar estas coasa para que funcione.

Donde encuentren esto **(except HttpError , e:)** lo van a tener que cambiar por esto **(except HttpError as e:)**

Y todos los argumentos de la funcion **print** tienen que ir entre parentesis
**print("lo que sea")**

Dicho esto, el problema que me está dando este código es el siguiente, básicamnete cuando lo intento usar me sale este error. (badRequest,  invalidRequest, Los metadatos de la solicitud no son válidos)

```
An HTTP error 400 occurred:
b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.video",\n    "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata",\n    "message": "The request metadata is invalid.",\n    "locationType": "other",\n    "location": "body"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "The request metadata is invalid."\n }\n}\n'
```

Esto es la ayuda del programa: (que ayuda mas bien poco) :-)

```
usage: youtube_update.py 
[--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
[--noauth_local_webserver]
[--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT]]]                                                                                   [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
**--video-id VIDEO_ID [--tag TAG]**
```

Los tres primeros parametros creo que se pueden omitir porque son leidos automaticamente desde un archivo (client_secrets.json) que creas con unos datos que te da Google. Este archivo lo he probado con los otros ejemplos y funciona, así que descarto algún error en él.

Dicho esto solo queda decir cómo estoy ejecutado el programa, y es así.

```
py -3 ./youtube_update.py --video-id  xxxxx  --tag title="algo"
```

Si intento poner mas cosas, por ejemplo la descrpción el vídeo así.

```
py -3 ./youtube_update.py --video-id  xxxxx  --tag title="algo" description="algo"
```

El programa me da errores de sintaxis (vamos, que lo estoy ejecutando mal)

```
youtube_update.py: error: unrecognized arguments: description=algo
```

Pues eso, si alguien sabe usar este código o tiene idea de cómo se debe usar sería estupendo que lo comentara por ahí abajo.

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok, la persona que me contestó me dijo que el ejemplo de Google era muy limitado, así que yo sin tener ni idea de python :-) lo que he hecho ha sido fusionar el ejemplo de Google de esta página.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es-419
Con otro ejemplo que estaba mas elaborado pero que tampoco funcionaba bien porque usaba un método anticuado de autentificación en google y lo saqué de esta otra página.
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py

El código final quedó así:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Update the snippet metadata for a video. Sample usage:
#   python update_video.py --video-id=<VIDEO_ID> --tags="<TAG1, TAG2>" --title="New title" --description="New description"

import httplib2
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))




def update_video(youtube, args):
  # Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
  videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(
    id=args.video_id,
    part='snippet'
  ).execute()

  # If the response does not contain an array of 'items' then the video was
  # not found.
  if not videos_list_response['items']:
    print ('Video "%s" was not found.' % args.video_id)
    sys.exit(1)

  # Since the request specified a video ID, the response only contains one
  # video resource. This code extracts the snippet from that resource.
  videos_list_snippet = videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']

  # Set video title, description, default language if specified in args.
  if args.title:
    videos_list_snippet['title'] = args.title
  if args.description:
    videos_list_snippet['description'] = args.description

  # Preserve any tags already associated with the video. If the video does
  # not have any tags, create a new array. Append the provided tag to the
  # list of tags associated with the video.
  if 'tags' not in  videos_list_snippet:
    videos_list_snippet['tags'] = []
  if args.tags:
    videos_list_snippet['tags'] = args.tags.split(',')
  elif args.add_tag:
    videos_list_snippet['tags'].append(args.add_tag)

  print(videos_list_snippet);

  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=videos_list_snippet,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute()

  print('The updated video metadata is:\n' +
        'Title: ' + videos_update_response['snippet']['title'] + '\n')
  if videos_update_response['snippet']['description']:
    print ('Description: ' +
           videos_update_response['snippet']['description'] + '\n')
  if videos_update_response['snippet']['tags']:
    print ('Tags: ' + ','.join(videos_update_response['snippet']['tags']) + '\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--video-id", help="ID of video to update.",
    required=True)
  #argparser.add_argument("--tag", default="youtube",    help="Additional tag to add to video.")
  #------------------------------------------------------------
  #replaces the existing list of tags
  argparser.add_argument("--tags", default="youtube", help="Comma-separated list of tags relevant to the video. This argument")
  #This argument does not affect current tags
  argparser.add_argument("--add_tag", help="Additional tag to add to video.")
  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Title of the video.")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Description of the video.")
  #------------------------------------------------------------


  args = argparser.parse_args()

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    update_video(youtube, args)
  except HttpError as e:
    print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
  else:
    print ("Tag '%s' was added to video id '%s'." % (args.tag, args.video_id))
```

El código se ejecuta de esta forma

```
py -3 ./my_youtube_update_snippet.py --video-id xxxx --tags="TAG1" --title="New title" --description="New description"
```

Y lo que ocurre es esto, se conecta a Youtube, y me muestra los metadatos actuales del video y también los metadatos nuevos que he ingresado. (hasta ahí todo bien)...

Pero al final acaba nuevamente mostrandome este error

```
An HTTP error 400 occurred:
b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.video",\n    "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata",\n    "message": "The request metadata is invalid.",\n    "locationType": "other",\n    "location": "body"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "The request metadata is invalid."\n }\n}\n'
```

Y los datos del vídeo no se actualizan.

Púes eso, ya no entiendo nada. Ya no es un error de sintaxis al ejecutar el programa. O el error está en el propio código o es un problema con el servidor de YouTube...

Cuanquier ayuda, opinión, colaboración será bienvenida!!

Comment: Parece que el código python no es más que un ejemplo bastante limitado, pues no permite cambiar el título ni la descripción, sino tan sólo añadir un tag a la lista de tags que tuviera el vídeo. Para ello la sintaxis sería `python3 youtube_update.py --video-id xxxx --tag foo`

Comment: Hola abulafia!! Gracias por contestar. Acabo de probar con esa sintaxis y tampoco funciona... Vaya, si estás en lo correcto y es un ejemplo muy limitado menudo fiasco... encotre este otro código que parece mas completo pero que al probarlo tampoco funciona... por lo visto está usando librerias deprecadas (desactualizadas)... a ver si puedo hacer que funcione... cualquier ayuda será bienvenida. https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py

Comment: ¿Por qué no te funciona con la sintaxis que propuse? ¿Qué error te da? Entiendo por otro lado que la idea de ese código es mostrar un ejemplo de cómo se haría un cliente python, para que partiendo del ejemplo lo amplíes para añadirle más funcionalidad que puedas necesitar (como cambiar el título, descripción u otros metadatos)

Comment: El mismo.. An HTTP error 400 occurred.... (badRequest ,invalidRequest, Los metadatos de la solicitud no son válidos.)

Comment: SI voy a intentarlo a ver si lo puedo fusionar con este. https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py ... aunque no tengo ni idea de python, lo mio es el C++, pero por intentarlo no se pierde nada

Comment: Ese tiene mejor pinta. No parece que tengas que fusionar nada, parece que debería funcionar sin más.

Comment: Ya lo he probado, usa el método antiguo de verificación... me da un enlace y cuando lo abro me da este error ...  


400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oaut

Comment: Intentaré fusionarlos a ver que pasa, toco madera!! :-)

Comment: Hola Abulafia. Al final hice la fusión que te dije, pero básicamente sigue dando el mismo error. No comprendo lo que está pasando... He puesto el código ahí arriba con la explicación de lo que ocurre por si quieres leerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mas vale tarde que nunca! :-)
Aquí está el código que funciona al 100% por si a alguien le interesa. Llevo usandolo dos semanas y va estupendamente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Update the snippet metadata for a video. Sample usage:
#   python update_video.py --video-id=<VIDEO_ID> --tags="<TAG1, TAG2>" --title="New title" --description="New description"

import httplib2
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))




def update_video(youtube, args):


  # Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
  videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(
    id=args.video_id,
    part='snippet'
  ).execute()
  print ('Call the APIs videos.list method to retrieve the video resource --> OK')
  #videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']
  #print(videos_list_response);


  # If the response does not contain an array of 'items' then the video was not found.
  if not videos_list_response['items']:
    print ('Video "%s" was not found.' % args.video_id)
    sys.exit(1) 


  videos_list_snippet={}
  #Guardar Valores Anteriores
  videos_list_snippet['title'] = videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
  videos_list_snippet['description'] = videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']['description']
  videos_list_snippet['categoryId'] = videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']['categoryId']  
  videos_list_snippet['tags']= videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']['tags']
  #["Electronic", "Royalty Free Music", "music musica", "Creative Commons", "no copyright music", "Musica sin copyright"]


  videos_list_status={}
  videos_list_status['privacyStatus']="public"
  videos_list_status['license']="youtube"
  videos_list_status['embeddable']="true" 
  videos_list_status['publicStatsViewable']="true"

  # Set video title, description, default language if specified in args.
  if args.title:
    videos_list_snippet['title'] = args.title
  if args.description:
    videos_list_snippet['description'] = args.description
  if args.categoryId:
    videos_list_snippet['categoryId'] = args.categoryId




  # Preserve any tags already associated with the video. If the video does
  # not have any tags, create a new array. Append the provided tag to the
  # list of tags associated with the video.


  # Nevas etiquetas
  if args.tags:
    videos_list_snippet['tags'] = args.tags.split(',')

  # Añadir una etiqueta
  if args.add_tag:   
    videos_list_snippet['tags'].append(args.add_tag)

  # Añadir varias etiquetas 
  if args.add_tags:
    videos_list_snippet['tags'] = list(merge(videos_list_snippet['tags'], args.add_tags.split(',')))

  #print(videos_list_snippet);



  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=dict(
      status=videos_list_status,
      snippet=videos_list_snippet,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute()

  print('The updated video metadata is:\n' +
        'Title: ' + videos_update_response['snippet']['title'] + '\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--video-id", help="ID of video to update.",
    required=True)

  #replaces the existing list of tags
  argparser.add_argument("--tags", default="youtube", help="Comma-separated list of tags relevant to the video. This argument")
  #This argument does not affect current tags
  argparser.add_argument("--add_tag", help="Additional tag to add to video.")  
  #This argument does not affect current tags
  argparser.add_argument("--add_tags", help="Additional tags to add to video.")


  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Title of the video.")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Description of the video.")  
  argparser.add_argument('--description-file', dest='description_file', 
    help='Description file', default=None)  
  argparser.add_argument('--categoryId', help='Category Video Id', default="10")    



  args = argparser.parse_args() 

  #utf-8
  if args.description_file is not None and os.path.exists(args.description_file):
    with open(args.description_file, encoding="latin-1") as file:
      args.description = file.read()



  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    update_video(youtube, args)
  except HttpError as e:
    print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Comment: ¡Me alegra muchísimo que hayas podido solucionar el problema! Te sugiero que le des una revisión a estos enlaces: https://argentinaenpython.com/quiero-aprender-python/ y http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/pythonya/ Sigue elevando ese cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!! Saludos :D

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyfx, miraré esos enlaces!! Un Saludo!!

Comment: de nada hermano, vas a llegar lejos con la actitud que tienes :D creces profesionalmente y la comunidad crece contigo, la comunidad crece y tú creces con ella #HermandadSOes!